# Graph Representation of data using PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Hello there I need to represent data in graph form(chart form). For this I am using a jQuery plugin .The problem I am having is when I do this using PHP array its not working for me.

The code I am using is here.

```
<html>
<head>

<title>JSChart</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../sources/jscharts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="graph">Loading graph...</div>
<?php
   $phpArray = array("Peter"=>"35","Ben"=>"37","Joe"=>"43");
 $aa= json_encode($phpArray);

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData =  <?php echo $aa; ?>;
        alert(myData);
    var colors = ['#AF0202', '#EC7A00', '#FCD200', '#81C714'];
    var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'bar');
    myChart.setDataArray(myData);
    myChart.colorizeBars(colors);
    myChart.setTitle('Year-to-year growth in home broadband penetration in U.S.');
    myChart.setTitleColor('#8E8E8E');
    myChart.setAxisNameX('');
    myChart.setAxisNameY('%');
    myChart.setAxisColor('#C4C4C4');
    myChart.setAxisNameFontSize(16);
    myChart.setAxisNameColor('#999');
    myChart.setAxisValuesColor('#7E7E7E');
    myChart.setBarValuesColor('#7E7E7E');
    myChart.setAxisPaddingTop(60);
    myChart.setAxisPaddingRight(140);
    myChart.setAxisPaddingLeft(150);
    myChart.setAxisPaddingBottom(40);
    myChart.setTextPaddingLeft(105);
    myChart.setTitleFontSize(11);
    myChart.setBarBorderWidth(1);
    myChart.setBarBorderColor('#C4C4C4');
    myChart.setBarSpacingRatio(50);
    myChart.setGrid(false);
    myChart.setSize(616, 321);
    myChart.setBackgroundImage('chart_bg.jpg');
    myChart.draw();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the below code is running perfectly.(with javascript array)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myData = new Array(['Mar04-Mar05', 21], ['Mar05-Mar06', 28], ['Mar06-Mar07', 12], ['Mar07-Mar08', 17]);
        alert(myData);
    var colors = ['#AF0202', '#EC7A00', '#FCD200', '#81C714'];
    var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'bar');
    myChart.setDataArray(myData);
    myChart.colorizeBars(colors);
    myChart.setTitle('Year-to-year growth in home broadband penetration in U.S.');
    myChart.setTitleColor('#8E8E8E');
    myChart.setAxisNameX('');
    myChart.setAxisNameY('%');
    myChart.setAxisColor('#C4C4C4');
    myChart.setAxisNameFontSize(16);
    myChart.setAxisNameColor('#999');
    myChart.setAxisValuesColor('#7E7E7E');
    myChart.setBarValuesColor('#7E7E7E');
    myChart.setAxisPaddingTop(60);
    myChart.setAxisPaddingRight(140);
    myChart.setAxisPaddingLeft(150);
    myChart.setAxisPaddingBottom(40);
    myChart.setTextPaddingLeft(105);
    myChart.setTitleFontSize(11);
    myChart.setBarBorderWidth(1);
    myChart.setBarBorderColor('#C4C4C4');
    myChart.setBarSpacingRatio(50);
    myChart.setGrid(false);
    myChart.setSize(616, 321);
    myChart.setBackgroundImage('chart_bg.jpg');
    myChart.draw();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not working = ?
chart not shoing up in page?

Comment: @lozadaOmr: as output its not showing me array data in alert box , it is showing "object object".

Answer (score 0):

The chart object is expecting a 2D array (an array inside an array).

If you look in the HTML source you will see that `json_encode` is giving you an object, which would look something like this:

```
{"Peter", "35", "Ben", "37", "Joe", "43"}
```

try using this:

```
function create_2d_array($array) {
    if (count($array) == 0)
        return "[]";

    $results = "[";
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $results .= "[\"$key\", $value], ";
    }

    $results = substr($results, 0, strlen($results) - 2);
    return $results . "]";
}
```

and in the javascript area:

```
var myData =  <?php echo create_2d_array($phpArray) . ';'; ?>;
```

Comment: when i print(echo) the $aa its is printing  "{"Peter":"35","Ben":"37","Joe":"43"}" . and i have tried your suggestion but it is showing 1d array in alertbox

Comment: When I test it I get a 2D array, it is possible that the chart/graph only accepts numbers. try removing the quotes (") from the value in my function and change your values to numbers instead of strings

Comment: I edited the question and removed the quotes from the value in the function.

Comment: i have a table of users with name and age.how can i convert it as 2d array.